# JavaFX tab is missing from Netbeans 8.0's Java Platform Manager

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

When I follow the step in https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/javafx-setup.html#create-platform-manual, I expect I will be getting a JavaFX tab

[image]

However, what I'm getting from latest Netbeans 8 is

[image]

**The JavaFX tab is missing!**

I can see `jfxrt.jar` at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib`. Is there any workaround I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell what you are after but I beleive JavaFX functionality is already there for you.

I am using NetBeans 8.0 with JDK 1.7.0_51 as a default platform and I also don't have any JavaFX tab but I am able to work with JavaFX projects. I can load for example one of the samples for JavaFX:DigitalClock. I can build it and run it.

The tutorial you point to refers to Netbeans 7.3. Also the second of the first two notes says:

`If you are using NetBeans IDE 7.4, you do not need to set up an "FX-enabled" Java platform in order to utilize JavaFX support in the IDE. You can develop JavaFX projects in the IDE if you install any standard Java platform that is JDK 7 Update 6 or newer (JDK 7 Update 10 or newer is strongly recommended). See NetBeans IDE 7.4 Release Notes for details.`

EDIT:
This is from `NetBeans IDE 8.0 Release Notes`: https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/relnotes.html#javafx

```
- The JavaFX SDK is not bundled with the NetBeans IDE 8.0 release.
- The JavaFX 2.2 SDK (and newer) is bundled with the latest JDK 7 for Windows, OS X and Linux. You can install the JavaFX 2.2.51 SDK together with Java SE Development Kit 7u51 as a co-bundled product.
- The JavaFX 8 SDK is bundled with JDK 8 for Windows, OS X and Linux. You can install the JavaFX 8 SDK together with Java SE Development Kit 8 as a co-bundled product.
- Unlike previous versions of NetBeans IDE, NetBeans IDE 8.0 does not require that you set up an "FX-enabled" Java platform in order to utilize JavaFX support in the IDE. You can develop JavaFX projects in the IDE if you install any standard Java platform that is JDK 7 Update 6 or newer (JDK 7 Update 10 or newer is strongly recommended).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add jfxrt.jar as an external jar/lib, that will enable you to use JavaFX APIs. In JDK8 jfxrt is included by default.